# include в Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, как можно в file.js вставить file.html. Например в PHP есть функция include();
А как это сделать в Javascript ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>

Comment: Ну это только если в файле находится JS-код. HTML в чистом виде в таких файлах не поддерживается...

Comment: На PHP что-то типа:

     <script>
       var html = <?= json_encode( $html ) ?>
     </script>

Но так лучше не делать, для того, что-бы получить данные с сервера лучше, использовать ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример на jQuery:

```
$("#content").load("page.html")
```

Загрузит страницу `page.html` в элемент с `id = 'content'`.
Естественно, это загрузит HTML в текущий HTML, а не в JS. Как уже отметили, загрузить именно HTML в JS нельзя - подумайте сами.

Answer (score 5):

include в javascript :) Отвечаю на сабж, а не описание.

```
function includeScript(src) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = src;
  s.async = false;
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.onload = arguments[1] || null;
  s.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete' && typeof(this.onload) == 'function')
        this.onload();
    }
  };
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
  return s;
}
```

Юзэдж:

```
includeScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js', function() {
  alert('jQuery v.'+$.fn.jquery+' loaded!');
});
```

Comment: Сразу не сообразил как вызывается колбек пока не обратил внимание на `arguments[1]`. Есть смысл добавить второй параметр в функцию в явном виде. Будет нагляднее.

Answer (score 2):

В *.js нельзя вставить* .html.

Answer (score 1):

разве что кодом js создавать динамически элементы html и сталять их в  код

Answer (score 0):

А можно использовать `<iframe>` или `<frameset>` всё равно "фабричные" библиотеки так и делают при отключённом AJAX

Comment: P.S я хотел ответить ещё несколько дней назад но чёто не сложилось... Теперь решил всё же ответить...